# How can I normalize CMDeviceMotion/CMGyroData?

Tags: ios, user-controls, gyroscope, core-motion

I would like to normalize device motion so that a user holding the device in landscape at a 45 degree incline is treated as the neutral position (0,0,0).

The idea here is to get smoother and more natural feeling motion for moving a sprite on screen.

Without normalization what happens is that the relative motion accumulates in a way that after short time the user has to move/hold the device in an odd way to place the sprite back in the center of the screen. Successfully getting the sprite back in the middle of the screen sort of "resets" it again for a time, so I am fairly certain all gyro rotations are relative to how the device is currently oriented (the docs *seem* to be saying this as well).

I played with gravity a bit to see if there might be a way to use it to make a guess on how the device is oriented and using it as a correction. Not really sure that is going to lead anywhere.

So, in summary I would like a defined orientation to always represent the middle and all rotations to be applied relative to this attitude/orientation.

Hopefully that is clear enough.

Here is my class

```
import CoreMotion
import SpriteKit

let MotionManagerSharedInstance = MotionManager()

class MotionManager:CMMotionManager {
    class var sharedInstance:MotionManager {
        return MotionManagerSharedInstance
    }

   func startMotionManager() {
      if !self.deviceMotionActive {
             self.startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame(CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical, toQueue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {
                deviceManager, error in

        })
    }

}

func stopMotionManager() {
    if self.deviceMotionActive {
        self.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }
}

func radiansToDegrees(#radians:CGFloat, correction:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return (CGFloat(radians) * CGFloat(180.0 / M_PI) / correction)
}

func updatePosition(node: SKNode) {
    if let data = self.deviceMotion {

        let rollCorrection:CGFloat = 8.0
        let pitchCorrection:CGFloat = 8.0

        let forceX = self.radiansToDegrees(radians: CGFloat(-data.rotationRate.x), correction: rollCorrection)
        let forceY = self.radiansToDegrees(radians: CGFloat(-data.rotationRate.y), correction: pitchCorrection)

        node.physicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(forceX, forceY))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update: I think I have a couple of leads to go on that may answer my question.